# Downgrading from Yosemite to Mavericks with TimeMachine backup from another Mac

Tags: macos, backup, imac

I have an iMac mid 2011 with Maverick which i have replaced with a iMac retina 27" with Yosemite Preinstalled. I did a Migration Assistant to transfer files from old to new mac. Now i want to downgrade the new machine from Yosemite to Mavericks. Can i use a TM backup from the old machine made AFTER the migration, to do this? (Using the OS X Utilities restoring from TM Backup).

Answer (score 1):

Doubtful, [the minimum OS for the 27" iMac is 10.10](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i5-3.5-27-inch-aluminum-retina-5k-late-2014-specs.html).  You can lay the TM backup down on the iMac, but it will most likely panic on the subsequent reboot.

Comment: Ok. Is there another way to downgrade in my situation?

Comment: No, the newer hardware simply won't support the older OS.